# Difference between a temporary view created by `WITH` and a temporary view created by `CREATE TEMPORARY VIEW`?

Tags: postgresql

In PostgreSQL:

1. Does `WITH` clause create a temporary view or a temporary table? (If I am correct a view stores the code of a query, while a table stores the result of a query)
2. `CREATE TEMPORARY VIEW` creates a temporary view available only in the current session.

   So what is the difference between a temporary view created by `WITH` and a temporary view created by `CREATE TEMPORARY VIEW`?

Database System Concepts seems to imply that `WITH` creates a temporary view instead of a temporary table:

> Since the SQL:1999 version, the SQL standard supports a limited form of recursion, using the with recursive clause, where a view (or temporary view) is
> expressed in terms of itself. Recursive queries can be used, for example, to express
> transitive closure concisely. Recall that **the with clause is used to deﬁne a temporary view** whose deﬁnition is available only to the query in which it is deﬁned.
> The additional keyword recursive speciﬁes that the view is recursive.

Comment: where is that quote taken from.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A common table expression (CTE) is only available for a single query.

A temporary view (like a temporary table) is available for all queries in the current session.  It is deleted at the end of the session.

Comment: Thanks. (1) Does a  common table expression (CTE)  store code of a query just like a view, or result of a query just like a table? (2) What is a "session"?

Comment: @Ben . . . Actually, in Postgres, the CTE is usually evaluated and treated more like a temporary table.

Comment: Then what is a "session"?

Comment: from when you connect to postgres until you disconnect is a session.  `temporary` objects last for the session eg: `create temporary table` ...  unless they are dropped before the end of the session.

Comment: Thanks. Is CTE  a temporary table or a temporary view in SQL standard, and other RDBMS'? I was wondering if " in Postgres, the CTE is usually evaluated and treated more like a temporary table" is just for PosrgreSQL?

Comment: @Ben . . . Neither.  It is more akin to a subquery, available throughout a single query.  The optimizer can decide whether it is materialized once (more like a table) or if the code is inserted into the SQL statement (more like a view).

Answer (score 3):

They are not really the same as temporary views.

In postgres CTEs (`WITH` clause) is materialized into table-like
objects. while views behave more like macros

this effect is most visible when one of the columns is a function that has a side-effect or returns different values.

```
select generate_series(1,3) as n into temp table a;
```

a simple table with 1,2,3

```
create temporary view v as select n,random() as r from a;
select * from v as x join v as y on x.n=y.n;
```

Using the view: note that random column does not match.
The same sort of result can be had by substituting the view expressions.

```
   select x.n,random(),y.n,random() 
   from a as x join a as y on x.n=y.n;
```

or

```
  select * from (select n,random() from a ) as x join
        (select n,random() from a )  as y on x.n=y.n;
```

But with CTE:

```
with c as (select n,random() as r from a)
select * from c as x join c as y on x.n=y.n;
```

using the CTE note that the random column matches.

yet another way to make the same query is

Comment: Thanks. Is CTE a temporary table or a temporary view in SQL standard, and other RDBMS'? I was wondering if " In postgres CTEs (WITH clause) is materialized into table-like objects" is just for PosrgreSQL?

Comment: @Ben: the SQL standard only defines the syntax and the user visible behaviour of the SQL commands. It does not make any assumptions about the internal implementation. Whether the database "materializes" the data or keeps it in memory does not really matter. That's an optimization strategy. Other DBMS materialize CTEs if they become too big, or if they use special syntax elements. The bottom line is: a VIEW is a stored object (query) that is available always (until it's dropped). A CTE is part of a single query and only "exists" during the execution of the query.